# Combobox Arrow Up/down key do not fire in datagridview winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have problem with combobox in datagridview. Ok, let's me explain.
In my form, I have textbox, datagridview and combobox (add to cell in datagridview).

```
dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));
 dt.Columns.Add("clo2", typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
 dataGridView1.Controls.Add(comboBox1);
```

Begin I focus to textbox, and press Tab key, event CellEnter is fire.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
 if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);

            comboBox1.Focus();
}
}
```

In first row, I see combobox is focus but I can not use Arrow Up/Down key for change selectedIndex.
Please suggest me why, and give a solution for resolve this.

Comment: What are you doing in the SelectedIndexChanged event?  We probably need to see that code.  Why are you adding the ComboBox to the DataGridView control?  There is a DataGridViewComboBoxCell to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

brother you are adding a combobox class control to an other control datagridview try using datagridviewcomboboxcell and also elaborate your question what you are trying to acheive?